# How can i implement a class using :Interface?

Tags: c#, interface

How can i implement a method from a class that is extended to an Interface?

I have this Interface:

```
public Interface myInterface
{
      public static int myMethod();
}
```

And this class:

```
public class MyClass : myInterface
{
       // And I want here to implement the method form myInterface and i don't know how
}
```

Comment: An interface cannot have static methods.

Comment: You'll need to remove both the public and static modifiers on the myMethod declaration in the interface.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812329/anyone-has-an-alternative-to-using-static-methods-in-a-c-sharp-interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Interface` won't compile - change it to `interface`.
`static` can't be part of an `interface`.

After corrections the code would look like this for example:

```
public interface myInterface
{
      int myMethod();
}

public class MyClass : myInterface
{
       public int myMethod()
       {
           return 1;
       }
}
```

Regarding `static` and `interface` see a quote from http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/250972-Static-Inheritance/?CommentID=274217 :

> Inheritance in .NET works only on instance base. Static methods are defined on the type level not on the instance level. That is why
>   overriding doesn't work with static methods/properties/events...
>
> Static methods are only held once in memory. There is no virtual table etc. that is created for them.
>
> If you invoke an instance method in .NET, you always give it the current instance. This is hidden by the .NET runtime, but it happens.
>   Each instance method has as first argument a pointer (reference) to
>   the object that the method is run on. This doesn't happen with static
>   methods (as they are defined on type level). How should the compiler
>   decide to select the method to invoke?

Comment: +1 for actually noticing the static in the method signature (and the issue with this).

Comment: The `public` in the interface will also be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You declared your interface incorrectly. Interface in C# specified with `interface` keyword, in that exact casing. Also interfaces cannot contain static methods. For further details please refer to [Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) MSDN article.

Answer (score -1):

**Second edit**: shame on me. I gave  this answer before I had tested it, then realized I had never declared a static method in an interface before. It isn't supported, there's an SO article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259026/why-doesnt-c-sharp-allow-static-methods-to-implement-an-interface) that covers it

disregard the answer below...

Simply implement the method as  would normally:

```
public Interface myInterface
{
   static int myMethod();
}

//impl
public class MyClass : myInterface
{
   public static int myMethod()
   {
      //implementation here
   }
}
```

Edit: I had stated this would make the method callable from an instance of the abstract or concrete class, then realized I had forgotten it was an abstract method...

Comment: Interfaces simply cannot have static methods.

Comment: Indeed, hence the second edit explaining my mistake. Perhaps I'll move it to the top of the post...