# Static/singleton interface implementing class in C#

Tags: c#, singleton, static-class

i have a class that (*right now*) is static:

```
public static class Grob
{
    public static void Frob()
    {
        Foo.Bar();
    }
}
```

And that works well. Code calls:

```
Grob.Frob();
```

and all is right with the world. Now i want my class to implement an interface:

```
public static class Grob : IOldNewGrob
{
    public static void Frob()
    {
       Foo.Bar();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately that does not work, because [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259026/why-doesnt-c-sharp-allow-static-methods-to-implement-an-interface/7945206).

So i would try changing to class to a [*singleton*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx):

```
public sealed class Grob
{
   private static volatile Singleton instance;
   private static object syncRoot = new Object();

   private Grob() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      { 
         if (instance == null) 
         {
            lock (syncRoot) 
            {
               if (instance == null) 
                  instance = new Singleton();
            }
         }
         return instance;
     }
   }       
}
```

Which works well enough, except that it doesn't work - the code no longer compiles:

```
Grob.Frob();
```

In other languages it would not be a problem. i would create a global `Grob` function (called `Grob` because that's the name that existing code needs):

```
function Grob(): GrobSingleton;
{
   return Grob.Instance;
}

//and rename Grob class to something else
public sealed class GrobSinglton
{
   ...
}
```

except that C# doesn't have global functions.

In the end:

- i don't **need** a global function
- i don't **need** a static class to be able to implement an interface
- i don't **need** a singleton

i just want it all to work.

Comment: Why can't you call `Grob.Instance.Frob()`?  That's how singletons work.

Comment: @cdhowie i can call `Grob.Instance.Frob()`; but existing code doesn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just create a singleton which *also* has a static `Frob` method?

```
public sealed class Grob : IOldNewGrob
{
    private static readonly Grob instance = new Grob();

    public static Grob Instance { get { return instance; } }

    // Prevent external instantiation
    private Grob() {}

    public static void Frob()
    {
        Foo.Bar();
    }

    // Implement IOldNewGrob here
}
```

You should probably also read my [article on implementing the singleton pattern in .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) - there's really no need to implement the fragile double-checked locking pattern.

That satisfies both of your requirements of making `Grob.Frob()` work, and making `Grob` implement an interface. It's not clear whether those are your *only* requirements though - you haven't really explained *why* you're trying to do that - where the singleton or the interface come in.

EDIT: If the idea was that `Frob` was a member of `IOldNewGrob`, you can use explicit interface implementation like this:

```
public sealed class Grob : IOldNewGrob
{
    private static readonly Grob instance = new Grob();

    public static Grob Instance { get { return instance; } }

    // Prevent external instantiation
    private Grob() {}

    public static void Frob()
    {
        // Implementation
    }

    // Explicit interface implementation to prevent name collisions
    void IOldNewGrob.Frob()
    {
        // Call the static implementation
        Frob();
    }
}
```

Comment: Delegate implementation of my methods to....myself! Nice. **Edit:** Why not do that? Cause i didn't think of it. The singleton doesn't come in anywhere; it wasn't one before 25 minutes ago. The interface comes in when people take an `IOldNewGrob` rather than a `Grob`.

Comment: Oh, wait. i can't have `public static void Frob()` and `public void Frob()`. *Lemme check Jon's answer* Oh, you created a new `Foo` class. Perhaps using interfaces is overrated.

Comment: @IanBoyd There are various [libraries](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) that will take a static class and an interface and generate a proxy class at runtime, delegating the interface method implementations to the corresponding static method.  Whether the overhead of an extra dependency and one-time runtime code generation is worth it is a call you'll have to make.  It will probably result in simpler code.

Comment: @IanBoyd: I didn't create a new `Foo` class. I copied your implementation from the first piece of code in the question. It wasn't clear what you were trying to do, and you never explained that `Frob` was part of the interface. (This is where a *complete* example really helps.) You can use explicit interface implementation for this. Will edit...