# Use preview features & preview language in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-8.0

How can I turn on **C#** *preview* features in Visual Studio?

> The feature 'nullable reference types' is currently in Preview and "unsupported". To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version.

The project **Properties** does not offer **"unsupported preview of next C# version (preview)"** as an option:
[image: No preview C sharp preview available]

Comment: You need VS2019 and a .NETCore project to get the "C# 8.0 beta" choice.  Moving to .NETCore is the important part, .NETFramework 4.8 is feature-complete and won't get any goodies anymore, .NET v5.0 is core only.

Answer (score 6):

### Synopsis

In order to turn on the preview features, you need all these:

- Visual Studio preview (recommended)
- .NET preview (required)
- Change the Project Application settings
- Change the Project Build settings

### Step by Step

1. Download [Visual Studio 2019 Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview#top)
2. Download [.NET SDK Preview](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral) for Visual Studio
3. Check your installation from a cmd-line:

```
   > dotnet --list-sdks
   2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
   …
   2.2.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
   3.0.100-preview6-012264 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

1. Right-click on your Project → Properties → Application
   Pick the Target Framework
   (note the link to **Install other frameworks…** as well)
   [image: .NET Core 3.0]
2. In  Project → Properties → Build
   Select **Advanced…** (Advanced Build Settings)
   Select the desired C# version:
   [image: Unsupported preview of next C sharp version]

Comment: This assumes the OP wants to use .Net Core 3.0.  If the project targets a .Net Framework version, is this still possible?

Comment: see @hans-passant comment: C# 8 is only available in .Net Core.

Comment: In VS 2019 with core 3.1, it says "Automatically Selected based on Framework Version". the only way seems to be to use intellisense features of VS, or add `<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>` to the .proj file.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect actually no https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651472/does-c-sharp-8-support-the-net-framework

Comment: For me the issue was a wrong workingDirectory path in launchSettings.json

Answer (score 5):

I my case I needed to check this checkbox (and restart Visual Studio!)

[image]