# Visual Studio suggests C# 8.0 features, but compiler yields error

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-4.6, c#-8.0

In my projects Visual Studio gives me recommendations to use C# 8.0 features for Framework 4.6 projects, even though the default is specified on the Microsoft documentations to be 7.3. An example of one of the suggestions:

```cs
var i1 = "";
var i2 = "";
i1 = i1 ?? i2; //suggests i1 ??= i2;
```

[image: example of suggestion]

If I let VS correct the suggestions the IDE shows me no errors or warnings, but the moment I build I get a compiler error.

I know I can change the `langversion` in the .csproj file to get it to work, but that's not the point.

Why do I get suggestions and then proceed to get no errors until compilation?

In my memory I used to get suggestions to automatically upgrade the project to the `langversion` for 7.X features in the past, if I wanted to use features from that version.

Example of one of the .csproj files:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>MyProject</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MyProject</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  //... References & compilation files
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: show us the xml of your project file (*.csproj)

Comment: Weird, .NET 4.6 (4.7 and 4.8 as well) isn't supported by C# 8, as it needs .NET Standard 2.1 things to work. More [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/building-c-8-0/) under "Platform Dependencies"

Comment: My VS doesn't suggest anything like this, are you sure it's not an extension? Try starting CS in safe mode (`devenv.exe -SafeMode` from the command line) and see if it still happens.

Comment: DavidG is right, might be ReSharper, it's been recommending C# 8 features to me for a while now

Comment: @MindSwipe Not R# here either, unless it's an older version.

Comment: @DavidG I have Visual Studio Enterprise 2019. No resharper, no other manually installed extensions. Just straight downloaded from the Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: And VS is up to date?

Comment: @DavidG Version 16.3.1, just saw there's a very new update out so I'm updating to 16.3.2. Also tried `-SafeMode`, but it yields the same results.

Comment: @DavidG I have the same issue using 16.3.2

Comment: Works fine for me with VS 16.3.0. I do get that suggestion in .NET Core projects, but not in .NET Framework projects.

Comment: Have done a repair through the Installer, but yet again. Same results

Comment: @404 looks like an Intellisense or analyzer bug. You can't use `??=` in C# 7.3, period. You'll *have* to change the language to C# 8 if you want to try this

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/752720/ide0054-and-ide0063-triggered-when-not-using-c8.html

Comment: According to [this more differentiated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57020770/880990) it is possible to manually set the language version in the project file and to use some of the C#8.0 features in the old Framework. Purely syntactical stuff can be used. Default interface methods requiring changes in the runtime cannot be used. Indexes and ranges and also async streams which require new types in the framework cannot be used.

Comment: The [Developer Community post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/752720/ide0054-and-ide0063-triggered-when-not-using-c8.html) referenced by @HansPassant was converted to a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39430), but closed because, according to the comments, it only occurs when `<langver>latest</langver>` is set. But that doesn’t appear to be the case in the OP’s `csproj` sample, so it seems the issue may have gotten lost in translation to GitHub, likely based on one comment pushing it in that direction. Is this still occurring on your project?

Comment: Occurs in my project in VS 2019 and my csproj doesn't even have a `<langver>`. It's also maybe worth noting that the build output shows the error but the Error List shows 0 Errors.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the **Microsoft.Net.Compilers** NuGet package worked for me.

I updated from 2.10.0 to 3.11.0.