# IAsyncEnumerable not working with in Visual Studio project that targets .Net 4.8

Tags: c#

When attempting to use `IAsyncEnumerable`, I get this error:

> The type or namespace name IAsyncEnumerable<> could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

How do I make this compatible with c# 8?

Answer (score 7):

Some *C# 8* and *.NET Framework* combination are not (and may not ever) be officially supported by *Microsoft*. It's dying a slow, painful death.

As of today [`IAsyncEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0) is only officially available for the following *frameworks*

- .NET Core 3.0
- .NET Platform Extensions 3.0
- .NET Standard 2.1

However, check out the following post, you might be able to mash it in

[Does C# 8 support the .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651472/does-c-sharp-8-support-the-net-framework)