# Compile Error When Using `record` Types With Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use a `record` with Unity3d. The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html) says C# 9 is now supported, but I still get the error:

> The predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit' must be defined or imported in order to declare init-only setter.

The documentation states this, but I'm not sure what it means:

> The type System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit is required for full record support as it uses init only setters, but is only available in .NET 5 and later (which Unity doesn’t support). Users can work around this issue by declaring the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit type in their own projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62656145/1213006) answer. You need to manually define `IsExternalInit` somewhere in your project, like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    internal class IsExternalInit{}
}
```