# How do I properly use C# 8 with .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-8.0, c#-7.3

So I'm trying to utilize C# 8 in my .NET 4 web application by adding two entries in my `.csproj` file right inside the `PropertyGroup` node.

```
<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

But for some reason when I try to do `string? name = "";` I still get an error stating `"Error  CS8370  Feature 'nullable reference types' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater."`

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 17.0.4.

Why is it that I get this error?

Comment: C# 8 is only available/supported (by default) when targetting .NET Standard 2.1 or .NET Core 3+ - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Comment: There was [some possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57020770/4137916) for the combination of .NET 4/C# 8 in Visual Studio versions of yore, albeit unsupported, but it may well be that VS 2022 does away with even this partial support (although it should arguably use a clearer error message then). Certainly NRTs are not fully supported on .NET 4 even where VS does allow the combo.

Comment: @phuzi That's not true - you can certainly use C# 8 with a .net 4.8 assembly.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I did say "by default" There is information on the linked page that describes how to override the default.

Comment: @phuzi Yes, but look at the OP's project setting `<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>`. They are *already* enabling C# 8.

Comment: Can you post your project file?

Comment: @MatthewWatson did ask you to show us your complete project file, but you haven't yet.

Comment: May I know whether your issue have been solved or not? if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use nullable reference types in .NET 4.0 web application, you can refer to the following steps:
First, unload your project, right-click and choose Edit Project File to open .csproj file.
[image]

Second, add `<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>` in the code:
[image]

Finally, reload project and add `#nullable enable` at the top of the file.
[image]

Comment: Is is possible to do this on the solution/project level?