# Does C# 9 support the .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

Similar to [Does C# 8 support the .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651472/does-c-sharp-8-support-the-net-framework)

I know that it's officially unsupported, but what features in C# 9 are available when using the .Net Framework (4.8)?

Features from -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history#c-version-9

- Records
- Init only setters
- Top-level statements
- Pattern matching enhancements
- Performance and interop

  - Native sized integers
  - Function pointers
  - Suppress emitting localsinit flag
- Fit and finish features

  - Target-typed new expressions
  - static anonymous functions
  - Target-typed conditional expressions
  - Covariant return types
  - Extension GetEnumerator support for foreach loops
  - Lambda discard parameters
  - Attributes on local functions
- Support for code generators

  - Module initializers
  - New features for partial methods

Comment: It's unsupported, but apparently some language features work. https://sergiopedri.medium.com/enabling-and-using-c-9-features-on-older-and-unsupported-runtimes-ce384d8debb

Answer (score 7):

To the best of my knowledge this is what is done by the compiler, and what requires runtime support (i.e. will not run on .net framework, requires .net core)

C# 9

- Records (compiler only for  .NET 4.0+, earlier versions would require additional work)
- init only setters (compiler, but needs class IsExternalInit)
- Top-level statements (compiler)
- Pattern matching enhancements (compiler)
- Native sized integers (eg nint and nuint, compiler)
- Function pointers (runtime I believe, wasn't able to verify)
- Suppress emitting localsinit flag (compiler, but needs class SkipLocalsInitAttribute)
- Target-typed new expressions (compiler)
- Static anonymous functions (compiler)
- Target-Typed Conditional Expression (compiler)
- Covariant return types (runtime)
- Extension GetEnumerator support for foreach loops (compiler, was already in VB)
- Lambda discard parameters (compiler)
- Attributes on local functions (compiler, can be used for debug only static functions)
- Support for code generators (compiler and ide)
- Module initializers (compiler, needs class ModuleInitializerAttribute)
- Extending Partial Methods (compiler)

Comment: Caveat: Record types directly generate a call to `Type.op_Equality`, which was introduced in .NET 4.0, so when compiling against earlier versions, each record type has to provide your own implementation of `Equals` that doesn't use it.

Comment: Extension GetEnumerator also has the additional requirement of the `ExtensionAttribute` class. I'm leaving *this* one as a comment (instead of editing the answer) because that's implied by being an extension method in .NET 2.0.