How to change the C# language version to 8.0 in WPF?
In this code example, I get two errors:
private Brush GetEventBrush(string eventType) => eventType switch
{
    "Created" => Brushes.LightGreen,
    "Changed" => Brushes.LightBlue,
    "Deleted" => Brushes.OrangeRed,
    _ => Brushes.White
};

One error occurs on the switch and one error on the _; both errors are the same:

Feature 'recursive patterns' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater.

I tried to make right click on the solution explorer project properties and then in build tab advanced, but the Language version is grayed out disabled.


Move to SDK-style project (so you can change <LangVersion/> in project file directly)  ... unless you are on VS 2019 - then you simply can't

@Selvin I'm on vs community 2022

Why are you on language version 7.3 to begin with?

Did you create a .Net Framework project?  If so, I'd create one based on a contemporary SDK instead of a legacy one and move code over.

C# 8+ is automatically available on the .Net platform (or more precisely, on Standard 2.1). Your project is most likely targeting the Framework. On the Framework, to get access to C# 8+, you need to "conjure" and without a guarantee of the result. For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57020770/13349759

try as follows
in Solution Explorer , right click your project, on popup-menu

click "Unload Project", then you can edit the project file,
after added latest , save file , double click project name to reload project
click "Edit Project ", save file

the code
  <PropertyGroup>
     <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>


See the warning in Configure C# language version: Setting the LangVersion element to latest is discouraged. The latest setting means the installed compiler uses its latest version. That can change from machine to machine, making builds unreliable. In addition, it enables language features that may require runtime or library features not included in the current SDK.

I know that, but , as a development machine, the newest runtime and SDK should be installed is the most basic requirement, right ?
