# Switch case on Enum values

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement, visual-studio-2019

> The feature recursive patterns is currently in preview, to use preview feature, please select preview version

```
switch (transactionRecieved)
{
   case TransactionType.TransactionName.ToString():
   break;
   case TransactionType.TransactionName1.ToString():
   break;
}
```

I am not using anything new. This is the general scenario and we use it all time like this for enum

> `TransactionType` is a enum

I also went through this post not found it useful.[SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639685/use-preview-features-preview-language-in-visual-studio)

> I need to use enum in swith statement and I am not able to use it.
>   could anyone help me on that part

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Your case values are not const, so you are indeed trying to use a new feature.

Comment: That code is not using enums, it switches on strings.  Deleting .ToString() is probably the way to get ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking "why doesn't this work"? I'm not sure you do use it all the time like that because `case` expects a constant value:

[image]

Parse your string `transactionRecieved` to a TransactionType enum with `Enum.Parse` or `Enum.TryParse<T>` and then remove the `ToString()` from your case, perhaps like:

```
    var x = "Whatever";
    if(Enum.TryParse<TransactionType>(x, out xEnum)){
      switch(xEnum){
        case TransactionType.Whatever:
          break;
      }
    }
```

Notes: 
* `xEnum` is in scope within the if

- `Enum.IsDefined` can be used in conjunction with `Enum.Parse` (but I find tryparse neater)

Comment: yes you are right Caius. I was doing it wrong. Thank you for the help